# How to implement AOP for someone else's bundles in OSGI (Apache Felix)?

Tags: java, osgi, aop, aspectj, apache-felix

I want to add **AOP** for classes of different bundles in **OSGI (Apache Felix)**

I need to create **Aspect** and to add crosscutting functionality into methods of each implementation specific interface. (prefered with help aspectj)

**Problems:**

- All implementations of aimed interface in different bundles
- Each of bundles have self classpath.
- We do not know witch bundles have implementation of interface

please help 8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OSGi [weavinghooks](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.weavinghooks.html) specification that covers weaving of classes for adding aspects.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/bdelacretaz/OSGi-weaving-hook-examples) of how to use it. The example uses asm but I am pretty sure you can adapt it for aspectj.

Another [example](https://github.com/prenex/equinox_osgi_skeleton) uses aspectj but does not have much doc and also misses a command line build.

Answer (score 3):

OSGi has a Weavinghook that allows you to intercept class loading. This hook allows you to inspect the byte code and modify it before it becomes a class. It also allows you to add imports.